# Parse Cloud Code with facebook API not working properly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I want to get a location Id from facebook API (that is already in my DB) and than use this to get the events from that location.

So, i'm first running a query to get this info and than adding this result as a parameter in my url. The fact is that the query is returning the result properly but when calling the httpRequest this is failling. Its important to say that my httpRequest works when I use the locationId hard coded.

I guess this problem is occuring because of the response calls but i cant figure out how to fix it. I'm also looking on a better way to design this code. Any ideas?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {

    var query = new Parse.Query("Location");
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            locationId = results[0].get("locationFbId");
            console.log(locationId);
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("Failed on getting locationId");
        }
    });

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/'+locationId+'/events?access_token='+accessToken,
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.data);
            response.success("result");
        },
        error:function(httpResponse){
            console.error(httpResponse.message);
            response.error("Failed to get events");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adolfosrs, your problem here is that your two requests are running asynchronously on different threads. Therefore, your first request isn't returning until after your second request has been called. I would suggest chaining the requests as below so that your second request will be initialized with the data retrieved from the first request.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Location");
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            locationId = results[0].get("locationFbId");
            console.log(locationId);
            Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/'+locationId+'/events?access_token='+accessToken,
                success: function(httpResponse) {
                    console.log(httpResponse.data);
                    response.success("result");
                },
                error:function(httpResponse){
                    console.error(httpResponse.message);
                    response.error("Failed to get events");
                }
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("Failed on getting locationId");
        }
    });
});
```